# Is is possible to ignore complete HTML within specified tag using HTMLPurifier

Tags: php, html, iframe, htmlpurifier

I have a use case where I need to store iframes and possible javascript generated dynamically in database. I am using HTMLPurifier to sanitize the input.

Is it possible in HTMLPurifier to ignore all content (HTML/CSS/JS) inside a specified element so it sanitizes everything but leave everything inside specified element intact?

Comment: why r u not using CDATA escaping???

Comment: Yeah, why not. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: Noup. HTML inside ckeditor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From **[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA)**:

> **CDATA** sections in **XHTML** documents are liable to be parsed differently
>   by web browsers if they render the document as HTML, since HTML
>   parsers do not recognise the **CDATA** start and end markers, nor do they
>   recognise HTML entity references such as &lt; within <script> tags.
>   This can cause rendering problems in web browsers and can lead to
>   cross-site scripting vulnerabilities if used to display data from
>   untrusted sources, since the two kinds of parser will disagree on
>   where the **CDATA** section ends.
>
> Since it is useful to be able to use less-than signs (<) and
>   ampersands (&) in web page scripts, and to a lesser extent styles,
>   without having to remember to escape them, it is common to use **CDATA**
>   markers around the text of inline <script> and <style> elements in
>   **XHTML** documents. But so that the document can also be parsed by HTML
>   parsers, which do not recognise the **CDATA** markers, the **CDATA** markers
>   are usually commented-out

**Here is the JavaScript Example:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.write("<");
//]]>
</script>
```

**Here is the CSS Example:**

```
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
body { background-image: url("marble.png?width=300&height=300") }     
/*]]>*/
</style>
```